# Python have import pygame but my vs Unable to parse "pyGame"

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, visual-studio-2017

[image]

I have load the pygame,and it can be run well in vs code, but I have wrong in vs, I have checked the environment of python in my vs, and it show that I have surely installed pygame but I just can't run it, and my vs said `Unable to parse "pygame"`

Comment: you may have many Pythons installed and VS may uses version which doesn't have PyGame installed.

Comment: oh ，thank you .i have newly build  a project rather than a file ,and it reminded me i haven't install "numpy" so i installed it as it said and succed finally